# Why doesn't my stored procedure work for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote a store procedure which can pick employee data either for his **CURRENT** job or **INITIAL JOB** or if **both** exists then only for **CURRENT** but I have achieve this for single employee only. I can't figure out that how to pick it for large number of employees in table because each employee can either have CURRENT or INITIAL or BOTH.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportEmployeeProfile] 0
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoReligion,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoPhoneResidence,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoPhoneoffice,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoNIC,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoName,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoMobile,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoMaritalStatus,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoGender,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoFatherHusbandName,
        CONVERT(varchar, PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoEntryDateTime, 106),
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoEmailAddress,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoDomicile,
        CONVERT(varchar, PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoDOB, 106) AS PersonalInfoDOB,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoComputerLiterate,
        PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoAddress,
        PersonalInfo.fk_WebUsers_PersonalInfo_UserID,
        PersonalInfoEmployeePicture,
        ServiceInfo.ServiceInfoInitialBPS,
        ServiceInfo.ServiceInfoInitialDesignation
    FROM PersonalInfo
    INNER JOIN ServiceInfo
        ON ServiceInfo.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID = PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID
    WHERE ServiceInfo.ServiceInfoJobStatus = ?
```

**Update:**
JobStatuses:
    1= Initial
    2= Prior
    3= Current

Comment: What does jobstatus mean?why are you setting jobstatus to 3

Comment: wait i am updating the question

Comment: @TheGameiswar please check

Comment: @TheGameiswar check now, I have changed my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `window function` will help you to solve your task. Take a look into this SQL code. I've used `ROW_NUMBER()` function to numerate all job status for employee and take last.

```
 SELECT T.* FROM
     (SELECT
            P.pk_PersonalInfo_ID, 
            P.PersonalInfoReligion, 
            P.PersonalInfoPhoneResidence,
            P.PersonalInfoPhoneoffice, 
            P.PersonalInfoNIC, 
            P.PersonalInfoName, 
            P.PersonalInfoMobile, 
            P.PersonalInfoMaritalStatus, 
            P.PersonalInfoGender, 
            P.PersonalInfoFatherHusbandName, 
            Convert(varchar, P.PersonalInfoEntryDateTime, 106) AS PersonalInfoEntryDateTime, 
            P.PersonalInfoEmailAddress,
            P.PersonalInfoDomicile, 
            Convert(varchar,P.PersonalInfoDOB, 106) as PersonalInfoDOB, 
            P.PersonalInfoComputerLiterate, 
            P.PersonalInfoAddress,
            P.fk_WebUsers_PersonalInfo_UserID, 
            PersonalInfoEmployeePicture, 
            SI.ServiceInfoInitialBPS, 
            SI.ServiceInfoInitialDesignation,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.pk_personalInfo_ID ORDER BY SI.ServiceInfoJobStatus DESC) AS row_num
     From PersonalInfo AS P
         JOIN ServiceInfo AS SI ON SI.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID= P.pk_PersonalInfo_ID) AS T
 WHERE T.row_num = 1
```

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 26
No column name was specified for column 11 of 'T'.

Comment: Add name to this column `Convert(varchar, P.PersonalInfoEntryDateTime, 106)`